# How to install shogun library on Google Colaboratory

Tags: python, anaconda, google-colaboratory, shogun

I want to use some tools from shogun machine learning library through Google Colab. However, I cannot install the package. I tried to install Anaconda and install shogun using conda, but after installation, importing shogun is unsuccessful. I tried to follow the instructions provided by the shogun official website, though it didn't help.

So, my question is how to install shogun in a Google Colab document? Is it possible in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can first install anaconda on colab,

!wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh && bash Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -bfp /usr/local

import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages')

Then, install Shogun with,

!conda install -c conda-forge shogun

Answer (score -1):

You can install packages in Google Colab using the the following syntax:

```
 !pip install shogun-ml
```

However, on the shogun-ml installation page they list the other installation options they have available:

### Install via atp-get:

```
!add-apt-repository ppa:shogun-toolbox/stable
!apt-get update
!apt-get install libshogun18
```

Then install the python 2 bindings with:

```
!apt-get install python-shogun
```

### Install via docker:

```
!docker pull shogun/shogun:master
!docker run -it shogun/shogun:master bash
```

Additionally this dockerfile would be appropriate:
https://hub.docker.com/r/shogun/cloud/~/dockerfile/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I tried it first. It gives me the following error:

Collecting shogun-ml
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement shogun-ml (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for shogun-ml

Comment: I've updated the answer to contain as many alternative installation methods as possible. If these don't work, the next step might be attempting to compile from source.

Comment: None of the suggested methods worked. I tried all possible options introduced in the shogun website, but none of them worked. Did you try this yourself? Are they working for you?

Comment: I guess we need to compile from source. That's the only option I didn't try.